# Difference between "use JSON" and "use JSON -support_by_pp"?

Tags: json, perl

Looks to me, the later one has more functionalities. But could not find specific doc for it. No "support_by_pp" found by grep under the perl lib directory as well.

Can someone please point it out for me?

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#JSON::PP-SUPPORT-METHODS)? The JSON module has two backends: a pure Perl backend (PP) and a C backend (XS). Some features are only available in the PP backend, but `-support_by_pp` makes some of these features available even when using the XS backend.

Comment: Yeah, it's helpful. btw, if I just put "use JSON", how can I tell which backend I am using?

Comment: That's also in the docs: https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#BACKEND-MODULE-DECISION

Comment: @amon - that should be an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`perldoc JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON)

The JSON module has two backends: a pure Perl backend ([`PP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON%3a%3aPP)) and a C backend ([`XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON%3a%3aXS)). Some features are only available in the PP backend, but [`-support_by_pp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#JSON%3a%3aPP-SUPPORT-METHODS) makes some of these features available even when using the XS backend.

To find out which version you're using, check [`JSON #Backend Module Decision`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#BACKEND-MODULE-DECISION)